# Is there other way to submit transaction without running cardano-node on my machine?

Tags: cardano-node

I want to use CLI to submit transactions and want to use an alternative tool that isn't cardano-node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
You can use the Blockfrost API.
It has a free level that might even meet all your needs.

Using curl you should be able to cook up what you need using the CLI but without the need for a Cardano node.

Here is the doc page for "Submit a Transaction":

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/~1tx~1submit/post](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1tx%7E1submit/post)